# Can I safely pass a reference into a detached thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Can I safely pass a reference into a detached thread? Is there a risk, that the referenced object is destroyed, and that the detached thread call the function on the destroyed reference?

I have a simple timer class that takes a functor and a period. The timer has a while loop with a thread that detaches.

The referenced object is instantiated once in main().

```
std::unique_ptr<Timer> TimerFactory::createTimer(std::chrono::milliseconds period, MyObject &object, void (MyObject::*function)())
{
    auto callback = [&object, function] {
        (object.*function)();
    };

    return std::make_unique<TimerImpl>(period, callback);
}
```

If not, would shared_ptr be the better alternative?

Best regards,
Stian

Comment: Using references is okay, but you need to document it thoroughly. Then if the users of your timer functionality let the object gets destructed before the timer elapses then it's the fault of the user.

Comment: It is not safe in general, you will need (by desing) to ensure that the referenced object will have a longer lifetime then the thread that uses it. If you cannot guarantee this its probably best to work with a shared_ptr to the object and capture that by value.

Comment: It seems fine at first glance here if the user if aware of this. Indeed, it *can* delete the object in the callback if needed. Otherwise, it would not be fair to ask the user to control the lifecycle of the object without knowing the exact lifecycle requirements of the `createTimer` (and in that case a `shared_ptr` is well suited). The thing is that deleting the object in a member function of its own class is not great at all (it generally results in bad designs)...

Comment: Great answers. Then it comes down to a design decision. I do prefer passing by reference over smart pointers when possible, but in this case, it seems like shared_ptr is 
 the overall safest option. Thanks !

Comment: Why does the timer class detach the thread? Detaching is almost always the wrong thing to do. And creating an object (which is what classes are for) that creates a thread and then abandons it doesn't make much sense. Having the object wait for the thread to finish helps remove lifetime problems.

Comment: @pete,  I think you are right. I thought I needed it, as I on the join would have to wait for a long time if I wanted to stop a long timer (it is using a sleep), but I never tested.... I was inspired by https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/28/timer-cpp/ . I changed it to a joining version, and it seems to work just as well. Need to do some more testing

Comment: @sangelsen -- thanks for the link. The guy is clearly not a C++ programmer.